# How to use LINQ to assign while selecting to new object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a data contract called `GameImage` and `GameTone`. I am trying to join the two entities, and assign a unique random position between 0-11 to an Image/Tone association. I am able to join the tables but am unsure if there is a way to assign the position while creating the object in a LINQ lambda expression.

```
            // Need random positions from 0-11 to to be associated to an image/tone
            var positions = Enumerable.Range(0, 11).Shuffle().ToList();

            // Associate image/tones
            imageToneData = game.GameImages.Shuffle()
                .Join(game.GameTones, gi => gi.GameId, gt => gt.GameId, (gi, gt) => new ImageToneData
                {
                    Image = new ImageData()
                    {
                        ImageFileName = gi.Image.ImageFileName,
                        ImageId = gi.ImageId
                    },
                    Tone = new ToneData()
                    {
                        ToneFileName = gt.Tone.ToneFileName,
                        ToneId = gt.ToneId
                    },
                    Position = // What goes here?
                });
```

**These are my data contracts**

```
[DataContract]
public class ImageToneData
{
    [DataMember]
    public ImageData Image { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ToneData Tone { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Position { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ImageData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ImageFileName { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
[DataContract]
public class ToneData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ToneId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ToneFileName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var positions = Enumerable.Range(0, 11).OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

  // Associate image/tones
            imageToneData = game.GameImages.Shuffle()
                .Join(game.GameTones, gi => gi.GameId, gt => gt.GameId, (gi, gt) => new ImageToneData
                {
                    Image = new ImageData()
                    {
                        ImageFileName = gi.Image.ImageFileName,
                        ImageId = gi.ImageId
                    },
                    Tone = new ToneData()
                    {
                        ToneFileName = gt.Tone.ToneFileName,
                        ToneId = gt.ToneId
                    },
                    Position = positions.First()
                });
```